# Leaflet, makers from mysql not show

Tags: php, mysql, getjson, leaflet

I'm trying show marker from db mysql. Data is not showed.

http://www.nexusmultimedia.it/gis7.html

```
    <script>
    var cloudmadeUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        cloudmadeAttribution = 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2011 CloudMade, Points &copy 2012 LINZ',
        cloudmade = L.tileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {maxZoom: 17, attribution: cloudmadeAttribution}),
        latlng = L.latLng(45.4404,12.3768);

    var map = L.map('map', {center: latlng, zoom: 11, layers: [cloudmade]});

    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup(); 

    function getUsers() { 
    $.getJSON("get_info.php", function (data) { 

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 

        var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng); 

        // var 
        var name = data[i].nome; 

        var marker = new L.Marker(location); 
        marker.bindPopup("<div style='text-align: center; margin- left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>"+ name +"</div>", 
        {
        maxWidth: '400'
        }); 
        users.addLayer(marker); 
      } 
    })
    };

</script>
```

from www.nexusmultimedia.it/get_info.php I can see:

```
[{"cf_id":"1","nome":"Cofano","lat":"45.475281","lng":"12.26436"}]
```

No error from browser chrome, but not marker is showed. Any idea?

Thanks

Nicola

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two issues. First, it seems like the response from the server is invalid because it isn't being sent back with the correct headers (Application/JSON). The response I see is simply the content of your PHP file:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=62.149.150.181;dbname=##your db name omitted##', '##omitted##', '##omitted##');
$sql = "SELECT cf_id, nome, lat, lng FROM form_data_MIT;";

$rs = $db->query($sql);
if (!$rs) {
    echo "SQL error\n";
    exit;
}

$rows = array();
while($r = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

print json_encode($rows);
$db = NULL;

?>
```

Secondly, you are not getting any errors in the console because you are adding the markers to a layer that doesn't exist - `users`. I think you meant to add each marker to the layer `markers`.

Hope that helps!